# Create custom buckets for each groups of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a custom buckets and labeled them with a category name.

buckets will be like `[0.0, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, 1.0]` and labels are like `["Top 10", "11-25", "26-50", "50-75", "75-90" ,"Bottom10"]`.

means if a rank falls between `0.0 & 0.1` then it will be labeled as `"Top 10"`.

My dataframe has 2 columns `category` & `Rank`. I want to create buckets for each category.

`pd.qcut` is not helping.

Comment: please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help in answering the question

Comment: `pd.cut(df['col'], bins=bins_list, labels=labels_list)`

Comment: Or use https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: @mozway will it work with bins as i have given?

Comment: @ggupta it should, although I haven't tested due to the lack of reproducible data

Comment: @mozway your answer is giving `bucket` as `NaN`. I'm using 

`q_labels = ["Top 10", "11-25", "26-50", "50-75", "75-90" ,"Bottom10"]`

`final_data['Bucket'] = final_data.groupby('category')['Rank'].transform(lambda g: pd.cut(g, bins=[0.0, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, 1.0], labels=q_labels))`

Comment: We can't debug without a reproducible example.